# VBA Format function, custom format to set numbers as millions with one DP not working

Tags: excel, vba, formatting

I am running some VBA in Excel 2010 to output numbers from tables within my spreadsheet to an external PowerPoint presentation. Because of the variety of numbers involved, I am using custom formatting strings specified in the tables which the macro is reading to determine the output format like so:

```
CellData = Format(SourceData,FormattingCode)
```

I have been able to get this to work with little difficulty for numbers in millions (0,,) and percentages (0.0%). However, I now want to do numbers in millions but displaying one decimal place, that is 1,200,000 should render as 1.2

The format code for doing this normally is (0.0,,) which I can see works in the normal cell formatting settings. However, when I pass this to the format function, I get the number to one decimal place unrounded with no separators like 1200000.0.

Any idea why this is? I know Format function is slightly different to custom formats in that it does not support any cell alignment features for obvious reasons, but can't see why this should be different. Anyone know how I can get the function to output the format I want?

Many thanks,

Comment: Why would you convert a perfectly good number to text-that-looks-like-a-number instead of applying the .NumberFormat property to the cell? Why not format(value/100000, "0.0") ?

Comment: What you're expecting doesn't seem like a job for formatting to me - 1200000 is not 1.2 so maybe you first need to divide by a million?

Answer (score 2):

`#,0,,.0`

This works in `format()` function in SSRS RDL. My actual full pretty out is
`[#,0,,.0M;(#,0,,.0M);'']`

Answer (score 0):

The VBA Format() function will struggle with some number formats, to convert a large value into millions with 1 decimal place, I use this.

```
Sub formatMillionsWithOneDecimal()

    Dim totalThisYear As Long
    Dim totalThisYearString As String

    totalThisYear = 17634600

    totalThisYearString = Format(totalThisYear, "£#,0,,.0M,")

    Debug.Print totalThisYearString

End Sub
```

This will output:

```
£17.6M
```

Comment: This functionally equivalent to the existing 4yr old answer by @MuppetBear

Answer (score -1):

The VBA format function can't handle this format string.  So:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim SourceData As Long
    Dim CellData As String
    SourceData = 1200000
    CellData = Format(SourceData, "0.0,,")
    MsgBox CellData
End Sub
```

will make an incorrect string.  Use this instead:

```
Sub dural2()
    Dim SourceData As Long, D As Double
    Dim CellData As String

    SourceData = 1200000
    D = SourceData / 1000000
    CellData = Format(D, "0.0")

    MsgBox CellData
End Sub
```

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

Use a cell.  Process it numerically.  Format it.  Convert to string:

```
Sub dural3()
    Dim SourceData As Long, D As Double
    Dim CellData As String, r As Range
    Set r = Range("A1")
    SourceData = 1200000
    D = SourceData / 1000000

    With r
        .Clear
        .Value = D
        .NumberFormat = "0.0"
        .Value = .Text         'convert to text
        CellData = .Value
    End With
    MsgBox CellData
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: This was what I was afraid of - I was hoping there would be a way that my VBA wouldn't need to be aware of what formats it was dealing with by encoding the data in the format string (that way one function could cover all cases). Are you sure there would be no other way?

Comment: @DrColossus  ***YES*** ...............I will update my post in a while.

Comment: @DrColossus  See my **EDIT#1**